# zoom to data during an animation

Tags: animation, paraview

I would like to make an animation of a growing 2D object in ParaView. I already found the follow the data filter for the camera, but this just centers the object throughout the animation. What I want is that the camera always zooms to the data to show the growing object in full size. Is there a way to do this in ParaView? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the Animation View, add a Python track. Double-click the track to edit the Python, and enter

```
from paraview.simple import *

def start_cue(self): pass

def tick(self):
    GetActiveView().ResetCamera()

def end_cue(self): pass
```

This should reset your view to see all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you want using a interpolation.

Select "View"(Alt+V) then "Animation View". A dock window will open under the Layout.

Select "Camera" from the dropdown menu, then select "Interpolate Camera Location".

Choose the first and last camera places in a way your data will always be fully visible. Then hit play to see result =)